# Is it safe to derive the Argon2 type from the encoded hash value?

Tags: c, security, cryptography, passwords

I'm trying to use the Argon2 reference implementation and I'm a bit confused on the use of the type parameter (i, d, id) during verification.

For password verification, I would need to call one of the `*verify*` functions of the library. These functions come with the "high-level" API:

```
/**
 * Verifies a password against an encoded string
 * Encoded string is restricted as in validate_inputs()
 * @param encoded String encoding parameters, salt, hash
 * @param pwd Pointer to password
 * @pre   Returns ARGON2_OK if successful
 */
ARGON2_PUBLIC int argon2i_verify(const char *encoded, const void *pwd, const size_t pwdlen);
ARGON2_PUBLIC int argon2d_verify(const char *encoded, const void *pwd, const size_t pwdlen);
ARGON2_PUBLIC int argon2id_verify(const char *encoded, const void *pwd, const size_t pwdlen);
/* generic function underlying the above ones */
ARGON2_PUBLIC int argon2_verify(const char *encoded, const void *pwd, const size_t pwdlen, argon2_type type);
```

The confusing part is why do I have to choose which method to call (or what to put in `argon2_type type` on the generic function), since the type is already contained in `char *encoded`?

From an application point of view, I would need to know which type was used for each password, beforehand. But... that's what encoding is all about. Wouldn't it be great if there was only one `*verify*` function?

```
ARGON2_PUBLIC int argon2_verify(const char *encoded, const void *pwd, const size_t pwdlen);
```

which would derive the type from the encoded value?

So, the questions are:

- Does the RI current API design tells me something about security, or
  usability was something the developers didn't really bulletproof?
- Is it safe to derive the type from the encoded value, or should I choose one type and stick with it (aka hardcode it)?

Thanks

Comment: Beware of using C in anything security related; the above code doesn't seem to perform any bounds checking etc. by itself. BTW, why not contact the authors for this; I've got very good results asking directly (of course you do need to be nice about it, e.g. start off by thanking them for creating the code in the first place).

Comment: I've opened an [issue on github](https://github.com/P-H-C/phc-winner-argon2/issues/234) a few days ago. I haven't received any answer, yet. I'll update this post if I get any.

Answer (score 0):

> The confusing part is why do I have to choose which method to call (or what to put in argon2_type type on the generic function), since the type is already contained in char *encoded? ... Does the RI current API design tells me something about security, or usability was something the developers didn't really bulletproof?

I'm afraid that's something only the authors can answer. However, generally reference implementations may not be as user friendly as those are meant for developers *of argon2*, not so much the users of the library.

> Is it safe to derive the type from the encoded value, or should I choose one type and stick with it (aka hardcode it)?

It makes sense to disallow downgrading and it may be wise to make this kind of filtering configurable.

In the end it is unlikely that an adversary finds collision even if the adversary has full control over the parameters - so it is not overly critical.

Personally I like to specify a specific *protocol version* separate from the actual parameters, which then specifies which algorithm to use.